# Como contar caracteres a partir de uma referência em Java?

Tags: java, string

Exemplo tenho um tanto de caracteres *123456789.123456789*.

Como fazer para contar até o `.` depois do `.` contar novamente lembrando que o ponto não deve ser contado.

Comment: `string.split(".")`não funcionaria?
Com isso vc teria um vetor de strings, com dois valores, ai poderia utilizar o método `lenght()` para ver o tamanho.

Comment: @GustavoCinque Boa sugestão. Por que não cria uma resposta?

Comment: Não tive tempo @André. Mas agora já fizeram, então, sem problemas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma outra alternativa usando [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-):

```
String str = "123456789.123456789";
// Como o índice da string começa em 0, indexOf retornará exatamente o tamanho da primeira parte.
int t1 = str.indexOf('.');
int t2 = str.length() - t1 - 1; // - 1 para subtrair o "ponto" do total de caracteres da string
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/eGlyVD)

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = "123456789.123456789";
//divide a string usando o ponto como divisor
String[] partes= str.split(".");
//antes do ponto
int n1 = partes[0].length();
//depois do ponto
int n1 = partes[1].length();
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra alternativa que pode ser utilizada é a classe [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) do pacote `java.util`.

```java
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("12.345.6789", ".");
    List<String> numeros = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
        numeros.add(st.nextToken());
    }
    // Vai retornar o tamanho da 1ª sequência antes do ponto
    System.out.println(numeros.get(0).length()); 
}
```

Exemplo funcional no [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/OOLnQR).

Em termos de performance, o `StringTokenizer` é mais rápido que o [`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), porém, `StringTokenizer` é lento quando comparado ao [`String#indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)).

No link abaixo é mostrado a comparação do desempenho de cada alternativa citada aqui, entre outras.

- [**Battle of the tokenizers – delimited text parser performance**](http://demeranville.com/battle-of-the-tokenizers-delimited-text-parser-performance/)